# Middleman contract to mint another ERC1155

Tags: remix, nft, erc-1155, mint, burn

Is it possible to create a middleman like contract to burn from one ERC1155 contract(Contract A) and mint another ERC1155 contract(Contract B) to the sender if he meets the criteria written within the contract.

When I tried to do it with remix, I can burn the token but could not mint the token from Contract B.

I'm getting the error

> The called function should be payable if you send value and the value
> you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the
> transaction to get more information.

I tried creating minter role or even transferring the ownership to the middleman contract, seems to get the same error still in remix.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/utils/ERC1155Holder.sol";

interface ContractA {
    function burn(address, uint256, uint256) external;
    function transferOwnership(address) external;
}

interface ContractB {
    function mint(address, uint256, uint256) external;
    function transferOwnership(address) external;
}

contract MiddleMan is Ownable, ERC1155Holder {
    
    address internal contractAAddress = 0x4D9f44094F448D949fc3EECa230A01d362529424;
    address internal contractBAddress = 0xa2e9669fC58d055D0aF1BaEd20dcF10A9e0DCb97;

    ContractA contractA = ContractA(contractAAddress);
    ContractB contractB = ContractB(contractBAddress);

    constructor() {}

    function burnAndMint(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _amount) public
    {
        // some logic to determine whether it can be proceed
        contractA.burn(msg.sender, _tokenId, _amount);
        contractB.mint(msg.sender, _tokenId, _amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see that the ERC1155 contract from openzeppelin wizard creates the mint function with `onlyOwner` modifier as you can see here

```
function mint(address account, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes memory data)
    public
    onlyOwner
{
    _mint(account, id, amount, data);
}
```

The issue you are facing is most likely because of this as the contract calling `mint` function is not the owner of the `ERC1155 Contract`

Here are a couple of solutions to fix this issue

1. Remove `onlyOwner` modifier from ERC1155 code
2. Make the `Middleman contract` the owner of that ERC1155 contract

Comment: Just edited it!

Comment: Did you used ERC1155 from the `openzeppelin wizard`?

Comment: I did use the openzeppelin wizard

Comment: I have gotten your issue !! i'll update answer shortly

Comment: check updated answer!

Comment: I have tried both solutions before but the error still persists.